# Running math file as batch job

Tags: scripting, command-line

I am trying to run the following *Mathematica* program,

```
ClearAll[f,g,L,s,k,h,L];L=100;h=30;

Do[f[i_,i_]:=-2;

f[i_,j_]:=KroneckerDelta[i,j-1]+KroneckerDelta[i-1,j];
g[i_,j_]:=KroneckerDelta[i,1]*KroneckerDelta[L,j]+KroneckerDelta[i,L]*KroneckerDelta[j,1];

K:=-(Array[f,{L,L}]+Array[g,{L,L}]);

vecs:=N[Eigenvectors[K],60];

Y:=N[Inverse[Transpose[vecs]].K.Transpose[vecs],60];

l=MatrixPower[Y,1/2];

P=N[Transpose[vecs].l.Inverse[Transpose[vecs]],60];

P2=P[[1;;L-s,1;;L-s]];

S2=P2[[1;;h,1;;h]]-P2[[1;;h,s+h+1;;L-s]].N[Inverse[P2[[s+h+1;;L-s,s+h+1;;
L-s]]],60].P2[[s+h+1;;L-s,1;;h]];

X2=N[Inverse[S2],60];

P3=N[P2[[1;;h,1;;h]],60]//Chop;

PA:=P3[[1;;h,1;;h]]//Chop;

XA:=X2[[1;;h,1;;h]]//Chop;

AA=N[XA.PA,60];

C1:=1/2 N[MatrixPower[AA,1/2]+ IdentityMatrix[h],60];

C2:=1/2 N[MatrixPower[AA,1/2]- IdentityMatrix[h],60];n=100/101;

M:=MatrixPower[C1,n]-MatrixPower[C2,n];

M2:=DiagonalMatrix[Log[Eigenvalues[M]]];ENT=Re[1/(n-1) Tr[M2]];

Print[s,"  ",N[ENT]],{s,1,20,1}];

Exit[];
```

this is running in *Mathematica* 10, but since I need to run the program for big size (`L=300`), I need to submit it as batch job(please find the script below), but it start to crashes for `L>=15`, I was wondering what would be the reason that it stops for bigger size when I submit it as batch job...

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -cwd
    #$ -j y
#

# Set up proper modules.
. /etc/profile
module load mathematica
module list

echo "Running on" `hostname`
# Run your batch/serial job.
math  -run  -batchinput -batchoutput   < chain_1d.txt > output.out

exit 0
```

Comment: Note that `clearAll` in the first line should be replaced by `ClearAll`.  Also, I recommend that you format the code in your Question as I did for you to improve readability.

Comment: I think you mean *batch* job, not *bash* job.

Comment: @setareh - just to nail down the problem, it runs fine in batch mode for `L<15`, but will crash for larger values?  What messages does it give in `output.out` concerning the crash?  Does it crash when you run it in the frontend for large `L` values?